# Config PhpStorm with Wamp?

Tags: php, server, wamp

I have a problem connecting PhpStorm with WAMP.

I have configured the PhpStorm (php interpreter to C:\WAMP:\bin\php), but when I run the code, my PHP script didn't run in the browser?

What's the problem?

Comment: Do you really have a Colon after `C:\WAMP:` There is a tutorial here based on XAMPP which is similiar to WAMPServer, you should be able to just change folder locations to those used by WAMPServer http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE

Answer (score -3):

If you are on a Windows machine I suggest using Apatna Studio or Phpdesigner.They are better then phpStorm. I had the same problem years ago, I just made the switch and now everything is great.

Comment: if i use Aptana or phpdesigner , do i have also to configure it ? or it's already per default ?

Comment: I'm not sure right now, I currently use something else now. Those were just suggestions phpStorm wasn't my best experience. I encourage you to give it a try.